# FCM behavior when offline for iOS

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having trouble figuring out how FCM behaves when I send a notification to an iOS device that is offline (e.g. in airplane mode, or turned off).

The documentation on the [`time_to_live`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl) property mentions that `Currently, time_to_live is not supported for notification messages on iOS.` but doesn't provide an explanation of what is done instead. I've tried testing it, and it seems like a push notification sometimes goes through, and sometimes does not, regardless of what I set the `time_to_live` property to be, although I'm not sure if that's due to throttling or something else happening on the FCM side.

Relatedly, I can't seem to get the `delay_while_idle` property to work on iOS, although the documentation does not explicitly mention that it isn't available for iOS - notifications that are sent while the phone is asleep still wake the phone, even if I set `delay_while_idle` to be true.

Does anyone have any insight into how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `time_to_live` is AFAIK applicable to both Android and iOS. However, since the process of sending the message to iOS devices for FCM goes like this:

> App Server > FCM Server > APNs > iOS device

It is safe to say that only the FCM Server makes use of the `time_to_live`, as per it's [description](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json):

> This parameter specifies how long (in seconds) the message should be kept in FCM storage if the device is offline. The maximum time to live supported is 4 weeks, and the default value is 4 weeks. For more information, see [Setting the lifespan of a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl).

Looking around, the behavior for APNs when sending to offline devices is (from the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1)):

> Apple Push Notification service includes a Quality of Service (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts to deliver a notification and the destination device is offline, APNs stores the notification for a limited period of time and delivers it when the device becomes available again. This component stores only the most recent notification per device and per app. If a device is offline, sending a notification request targeting that device causes the previous request to be discarded. If a device remains offline for a long time, all its stored notifications in APNs are discarded.

As of now, [`delay_while_idle`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) is now deprecated.

The way I know that you could do to *wake up* an iOS phone (online/connected to a decent network) is to simply [set the `priority` to `high`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message).